# SQL - counting not the whole rows

Tags: sql, relational-database

I want to get from every movie the id, name and number of roles which belong to the movie. I don't get how I count the roles. When I do something like join both of the tables and do `COUNT(role)` I get the number of all of the roles in all movies together.

[image]

I don't get how to separate the roles of the movies.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) ) An ERD is an image of DDL.

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask about 1 bad definition/query/function with the obligatory [mre] & why you think it should return something else at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do & ideally a [mre]. But please ask about the former 1st because misconceptions in the former will get in the way of understanding the latter. And bad code doesn't tell us what you wish it would do. [ask] [Help]

Comment: When pinned down & clearly expressed this will be a faq. (Clearly.) Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect research in posts. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [research effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097)

Answer (score 1):

COUNT is an aggregate function which can by used with a GROUP BY statement in order to specify subgroups on which the function is applied, in your case a certain movie.
`SELECT m.id, m.name, COUNT(r.role) FROM movies m INNER JOIN roles r on m.id=r.movie_id GROUP BY m.id, m.name`

Comment: ah the inner join , thank you.